# How to do Automatic synchronize between database access and DatagridView in c#

Tags: c#

in my program when i delete a record, it deleted from database access and from the DataGridView , but when i close the window and open it again the record appear again in DataGridView ,Although it deleted from database access ,Here is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection.Open();
    command.Connection = connection;
    string query = " delete from Hoteldb where ID= " +textBox0.Text + "";
    MessageBox.Show(query);
    command.CommandText = query;
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Guest Checked Out succesfly");
    BindGridView();
}

public void BindGridView()
{
    string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Hoteldb";  
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, connection);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(table);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Don't use concatenation, unless you want someone to enter `1 or 1=1` and delete the entire table. That's exactly how SQL injection works. Use parameterized queries and **DON'T** use global connection objects. You'll only end up blocking your own application. There are a *lot* of tutorials that show how to bind data to grids and update the database in response to UI commands

Comment: As for the actual problem, either the key doesn't exist, the text contains unexpected characters or you are targeting the **wrong** database. Are you using a user instance SQL Server database perhaps? Or an Access file?  Each time you debug your application the database file is replaced

Comment: i am using Access file

Comment: That's the problem then. *Content* files are always copied to the `Debug` folder when you start debugging. You *shouldn't* be storing user data in the program's folder anyway. The `Program Files` folder is read-only. You should store data either in the user's Documents folder or in the special `%ApplicationData%` folder

Comment: i did, the same problem

Comment: `I did` what? What path? Where is the database file? Either you are looking at the wrong database, or your code somehow *hides* errors.

Comment: in user's Documents folder

Comment: Did you change the connection string to point to the new location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int RowsAffected = 0;

    connection.Open();
    string query = "DELETE FROM Hoteldb WHERE ID=@ID";
    command = new OleDBCommand(query);
    command.Connection = connection;

    cmd.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("@ID", OleDbType.WChar, 150, "ID"));
    cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value = textBox0.Text.Trim()
    RowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if(RowsAffected > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Guest Checked Out succesfly");
        BindGridView();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was nothing to be deleted");
    }
}

public void BindGridView()
{
    connection.Open();
    string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Hoteldb";  
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL);
    cmd.Connection = connection;

    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds, "Hoteldb");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Hoteldb"].DefaultView

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: This is a CLASSIC SQL Injection scenario. What if the ID isn't a number? What if it contains `'` or `"`" characters? What if someone enters `1 or 1=1` ? Adding single quotes isn't going to fix anything

Comment: Yes. you should use parameters. I will update the awnser @MahMSL

Comment: same problem , the record deleted but when i close the window and open it , it come back again

Comment: the full code is long can i  send it to you by email?

Comment: If it does not work this is possible related with your connection with the database @MahMSL

Comment: yes ,you are right , the problem was with connection with the database             it is working now ,thank u so much

Comment: Make sure every time you do this kind of stuff us parameters to avoid SQLInjection @MahMSL